# "The couple argue/argues" in American English

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In American English, should "argue" or "argues" be used in the following?

> The couple often argue/argues about how to raise their kids.

Comment: Americans slightly favour the singular verb form [***couple argues***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couple+argue%2Ccouple+argues&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), but Brits prefer the plural verb [***couple argue***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couple+argue%2Ccouple+argues&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) It's only in the last century that Americans have adopted [couple IS seated.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couple+is+seated%2Ccouple+are+seated&year_start=1860&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=10)

Comment: That doesn't mean that 'everybody in America says _the couple argues_ and everyone in British English zones says _the couple argue_'. People in both zones say it both ways.